# Android WearOS tile does not show up

Tags: java, android, wear-os-tiles

I have a Java WearOS app that tries to implement a simple tile. The tile does not appear in the Add Tile list.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name='com.gncbrown.GetMeBackWatch.Utilities.GetMeBackTileService'
    android:exported='true'
    android:label='GetMeBack Tile'
    android:icon='@drawable/icon'
    android:permission='com.google.android.wearable.permission.BIND_TILE_PROVIDER'>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name='androidx.wear.tiles.action.BIND_TILE_PROVIDER' />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name='androidx.wear.tiles.PREVIEW'
        android:resource='@drawable/icon' />
</service>
```

GetMeBackTileService

```
public class GetMeBackTileService extends TileService {
    private static final String RESOURCES_VERSION = '5';

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<TileBuilders.Tile> onTileRequest(@NonNull RequestBuilders.TileRequest requestParams) {

        return Futures.immediateFuture(new TileBuilders.Tile.Builder()
                .setResourcesVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                //.setFreshnessIntervalMillis(60*1000*5) // 60 minutes
                .setTimeline(new TimelineBuilders.Timeline.Builder()
                        .addTimelineEntry(new TimelineBuilders.TimelineEntry.Builder()
                                .setLayout(new LayoutElementBuilders.Layout.Builder()
                                        .setRoot(new LayoutElementBuilders.Text.Builder().setText('Test').
                                                setModifiers(new ModifiersBuilders.Modifiers.Builder().setSemantics(
                                                        new ModifiersBuilders.Semantics.Builder().setContentDescription('lol').build()).build()
                                                ).build()
                                        ).build()
                                ).build()
                        ).build()
                ).build()
        );
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<ResourceBuilders.Resources> onResourcesRequest(@NonNull RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest requestParams) {
        return Futures.immediateFuture(new ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder()
                .setVersion('5')
                .build());
    }
}
```

I don't see my tile appear in the tile list for apps.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled and reinstalled my app and now I see it!